# How to adjust the ticks and label size of a pandas plot with secondary_y

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, yaxis, twinx

I have a plot with a left and right y-axis created with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) and specifying `secondary_y=True`.

I want to increase the font sizes of the y-axis tick params, but it seems that only the left side y-axis font size is increasing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample dataframe
sample_length = range(1, 2+1)
rads = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
data = np.array([np.sin(t*rads) for t in sample_length])
df = pd.DataFrame(data.T, index=pd.Series(rads.tolist(), name='radians'), columns=[f'freq: {i}x' for i in sample_length])

# display(df.head(3))
         freq: 1x  freq: 2x
radians                    
0.00     0.000000  0.000000
0.01     0.010000  0.019999
0.02     0.019999  0.039989

# plot
ax1 = df.plot(y='freq: 1x', ylabel='left-Y', figsize=(8, 5))
df.plot(y='freq: 2x', secondary_y=True, ax=ax1)

ax1.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=20)
```

[image]

What is the way to increase the font size for the right y-axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Access the `secondary_y` axes with `ax2.set_ylabel('right-Y', fontsize=30)`, or access it from `ax1` with the `.right_ax` attribute. `dir(ax1)` will show all of the available methods for `ax1`.

  - `.right_ax` does not work if `ax2` is implemented with `.twinx()`:

    - `ax2 = ax1.twinx()` and `df.plot(y='freq: 2x', ax=ax2)`
    - `ax2.set_ylabel('right-Y', fontsize=30)` works with `.twinx()`
- See [pandas User Guide: Plotting on a secondary y-axis](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#plotting-on-a-secondary-y-axis)
- **Tested in `python 3.8.12`, `pandas 1.3.4`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`**

```py
# plot the primary axes
ax1 = df.plot(y='freq: 1x', ylabel='left-Y', figsize=(8, 5))

# add the secondary y axes and assign it
ax2 = df.plot(y='freq: 2x', secondary_y=True, ax=ax1)

# adjust the ticks for the primary axes
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=14)

# adjust the ticks for the secondary y axes
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=25)

# set the primary (left) y label
ax1.set_ylabel('left Y', fontsize=18)

# set the secondary (right) y label from ax1
ax1.right_ax.set_ylabel('right-Y', fontsize=30)

# alternatively (only use one): set the secondary (right) y label from ax2
# ax2.set_ylabel('right-Y', fontsize=30)

plt.show()
```

[image]

### Note

- If plotting **all** of the available columns, where select column should be on `secondary_y`, there's no need to specify `y=`, and `secondary_y=['...', '...', ..., '...']` can be a list.
- Because the secondary axes is created at the same time as the primary axes, the secondary axes is not assigned to a variable, but this can be done with `ax2 = ax.right_ax`, then `ax2` can be used directly.

```py
ax = df.plot(ylabel='left-Y', secondary_y=['freq: 2x'], figsize=(8, 5))

ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=14)
ax.right_ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=25)

ax.set_ylabel('left Y', fontsize=18)

# set the right y axes
ax.right_ax.set_ylabel('right-Y', fontsize=30)
```